# How to get all unique values from multiple dictionary keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've used `const unqX = [...new Set(data.map(item => item['x']))]` in JavaScript before to get all unique values for key `x`, but is there a way I can modify this to allow multiple keys as input? In this case `x` and `y`.

I would like it to return `['A', 'B', 'D']`

```
[
    {
        'x': 'A', <-- 
        'y': 'B', <--
        'z': 'C'
    },
    {
        'x': 'A',
        'y': 'D', <--
        'z': 'B',
    }
]
```

Comment: My first sentence says that I tried that piece of code. The problem is that I don't know how to use it with multiple keys. I don't think that's unclear from my question... But thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array for the wanted keys and [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for getting all wanted values.

```js
const
    data = [{ x: 'A', y: 'B', z: 'C' }, { x: 'A', y: 'D', z: 'B' }],
    keys = ['x', 'y'],
    unique = [...new Set(data.flatMap(item => keys.map(k => item[k])))];

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Didn't know `flatMap` existed. Thanks!